# Doesn't Spring really support Interface injection at all?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I know that Spring doesn't supports Interface injection and I've read that many a times.

But today as I came across an article about IOC by Martin Fowler ([link](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#InterfaceInjection)), it seems using ApplicationContextAware in Spring is some what similar to the Interface injection.

when ever Spring' context reference is required in our Spring bean, we'll implement  ApplicationContextAware and will implement the setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) method, and we'll include the bean in the config file. Is not this the same as Interface injection, where where telling the Spring to inject (or), say, pass the reference of the context into this bean?

Or I m missing something here? Thanks for any information!

ManiKanta

Comment: Sounds like you've been reading some bad stuff, Spring very much *does* support interface injection.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'interface injection'? I only have about 100 examples of a bean that defines void setSomething(Something) where Something is an interface, not a class, and spring is perfectly happy to inject class instances that implement the interface?

Comment: @skaffman I didn't see that Spring supports Interface Injection, even in the Spring docs (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators)

Comment: @bmargulies Injection of an implemented bean for an interface is not what Interface Injection says. We'll inject bean dependencies by into our actual object by implementing the dependency bean's associated interface. So container calls the injector of that interface implemented when the actual object is instantiated. Pl check the IOC article by Martin Fowler (link is in the posted question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean interface injection [as defined on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Types), spring supports it out of the box for ResourceLoaders, ApplicationContexts, MessageSource, and others, with the interfaces [ResourceLoaderAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ResourceLoaderAware.html), [ApplicationContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html), [MessageSourceAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSourceAware.html), respectively.

It is also possible to extend this mechanism with new interfaces an depedencies by registering a [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html).

The Spring reference manual [explains](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-aware) this capability (and when one should (not) use it) quite clearly. BTW, I have generally found the spring reference manual to be much more reliable than what 'someone on the internet' says.

Comment: Yeah! Even though Spring doesn't actually supports Interface injection, still we can achieve the same effect practically using Autowiring technique (http://opensource.atlassian.com/confluence/spring/display/DISC/Adding+Interface+Injection+to+Spring). 

BTW, Martin Fowler is the guy who introduced the DI. Isn't it? So, may be we can check his article. Yeah, that article is in general. So all the article' content may not holds good for the Spring case.

Correct me if some thing is not correct!