# Spring interface injection example

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, interface

No one so far was capable of providing a working correct example of interface injection in Spring Framework.

Martin Fowler article is not for mortals, everything else just words positioned in a very confusing way. I have surfed over THIRTY articles, where people either tell "Spring doesn't directly supports for interface injection"("and because I don't know exactly how I will only describe setter and constructor injections") or either "I will discuss it in my other threads" or either there will be few comments below saying that it is wrong example. I don't ask for explanation, I BEG for example.

**There are three types of injection: Constructor, Setter and Interface. Spring doesn't support the latest directly(as I have observed people saying). So how is it done exactly?**

Thank You,

Comment: It's possible to downvote for other reasons than "not knowing about the topic", you know. What, *specifically*, do you want an example of? Define "interface injection" for the purposes of your question.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote was in response to your first paragraph rant and that fact that your actual question is vague and could easily be simplified to "Can someone give and example of Spring interface injection?  I have searched several sites and have yet to find one." (assuming, of course, that is your question) It might also help if you posted the articles you've read so people get a better idea of what you've already looked at.

Comment: In addition to the answer from @NimChimpsky (which is called AutoWiring in Spring and is supported through Annotations or XML), there's this SO question with a ton of resources on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827147/doesnt-spring-really-support-interface-injection-at-all

Comment: @Aubergine I'm asking what would interface injection look like to you in the context of this question--[the Fowler article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#InterfaceInjection) seems like normal injection to me, but via interfaces rather than classes. If you're at the stage of writing a dissertation it seems like the Fowler article should be pretty straight-forward--it's a significantly easier read than most academic papers on the topic, unless you're using "dissertation" in a sense other than "I'm completing my PhD".

Comment: I will correct myself if it is offensive to call bsc final project a dissertation. :-) Initially I though interface injection is when you pretty much use setters and constructors but provide interface instead. It seems example below is the same confusion or we are correct. And specifically this is the only Martin Fowler article for me which is difficult to understand.

Comment: @Aubergine Gotcha. I agree his example is somewhat opaque and ill-defined, at least IMO. Ultimately, though, to me it seems like "regular" injection, with another level of injection--everything is still injected via setters (the finder, the movie name) but the injectors themselves are... injected. This comment has not helped, I think ;)

Comment: check the other answer what do you think?

Comment: See my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31244931/1406510

Comment: [difference-between-spring-setter-and-interface-injection](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163175/difference-between-spring-setter-and-interface-injection/163287#163287)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [Variants of DI in spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators)

> DI exists in two major variants, Constructor-based dependency injection and Setter-based dependency injection.

Also see [Interface injection is not implemented in Spring](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/core-concepts-dependency-injection-to-the-rescue.html) clearly states it.

So there are only two variants of DI. So if documentation says nothing about interface injection, its clear that its not there. Those who believe that interface injection is done by providing setter method in interface answer me:

1. Why spring ref doc left mention of interface injection?
2. Why can't interface injection via providing setter method **NOT** considered as setter injection itself. Why create special term for that when introduction of interface doesn't affect anything, I mean its still configured the same way. If they were different then how can one find it via seeing the config. Shouldn't it be transparent that in config and not seeing the impl that actually configured class implements some interface ?
3. Just like [Instantiation using an instance factory method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method) and [Instantiation using an static factory method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method), some bean attributes should clarify the interface injection?

Comment: After giving quite a time to this problem myself I believe nanosoft spent enough effort to disprove other answers. At the very least there is  no evidence or examples which don't confuse the setter/constructor DI using interfaces with interface injection in Spring IoC. Again well done for research and insight.

Answer (score 10):

With interface injection an interface explicitly defines the point where a dependency can be set:

```
interface InjectPerson {
    public void injectHere(Person p);
}

class Company implements InjectPerson {
   Person injectedPerson; 

   public void injectHere(Person p) {
        this.injectedPerson = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the injection is done elsewhere. This just says "a company should be able to get a person injected".

Comment: That's work around not interface injection- http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/core-concepts-dependency-injection-to-the-rescue.html

Comment: @nanosoft Thanks, I upvoted your answer but still the resource you provided dates back as of Spring 2.0 asfaik. Now we have much more stuff, even if it wasn't back then with the magic of Spring Boot I see why they could not
just implement it. I guess I will have to ask the Spring guys directly via Jira ticket just for curiosity.

Comment: @Aubergine - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method is of spring 4.1.7.RELEASE. You can check by scrolling to the bottom of the page and click on Home link. On the top of the new page you will see the version 4.1.7.RELEASE. And in that ref doc, there is no mention of interface injection as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Hi I tried with a very simple approach that may clarify your answer.

following is the code that i have built on using two interfaces and and two bean classes.

first interface with name Job.

```
public interface Job {
    public void setmyJob(String myJob);
    public String getmyJob();
}
```

and one class to implement this interface with name as MyJob

```
public class MyJob implements Job {
    public String myJob;

    public MyJob() {
        System.out.println("From MyJob default Constructor and the ID= "+this);
    }

    public void setmyJob(String myJob) {
        this.myJob=myJob;
    }

    public String getmyJob() {
        return myJob;
    }
}
```

In the next step i created another Interface with name as Service

```
public interface Service {
    public void setJob(Job job);
    public Job getJob();
}
```

and then again another class to implement this Service Interface.

```
public class MyService implements Service {

    public Job job;

    public void setJob(Job job) {
        this.job=job;
        System.out.println("Hello from Myservice: Job ID="+job);
    }

    public Job getJob() {
        return job;
    }
}
```

then i created on main class with the main function and written the code as follows:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String...a) {

        BeanFactory beanfactory=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        MyService myservice=(MyService)beanfactory.getBean("myservice");
        System.out.println("Before print");
        System.out.println(myservice.getJob().getmyJob());
    }
}
```

in my Beans.xml file i mentioned the code as follows and it worked.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="myjob" class="MyJob">
        <property name="myJob" value="My First String"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myservice" class="MyService">
        <property name="job" ref="myjob"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I have also reffered to another online tutorials and then got this kind of solution. please let me know if you have any problem with this code. it is working for me.

Comment: Could you tell me the online tutorial where you got?

Comment: Well what makes it different from setter injection...? You have property job in MyService class which you are injecting essentially via setter method and hence setter injection... Just introduction of interface doesn't make any difference, I believe....

Comment: Interface injection is not implemented in Spring  - http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/core-concepts-dependency-injection-to-the-rescue.html

Comment: It is clearly written in the given link   that " It’s a different type of DI that involves mapping items to inject to specific interfaces."

This means that we need to specify which concrete implementation to inject for a certain interface. I have done similar thing. It could be a wrong way of injecting the concrete class but now what you have in your class is an interface holding the reference of its concrete class.

Answer (score 5):

There are 3 types of dependency injections:-

```
1. Constructor Injection(E.g Pico Container, Spring supports it).
2. Setter Injection(E.g Spring supports it).
3. Interface Injection(E.g Avalon, Spring does not support it).
```

Spring supports only constructor and setter based injection.
Looks like you got confused in the different types(3) and what spring supports(2 of them).

Answer (score 3):

I think, that the confusion around interface injection is caused by missunderstanding what the term "interface injection" actually means. In my understanding, interface injection describes the ability of a bean contener to inject a new interface to the bean, no matter that the class definition of this bean is not implementing it.

All examples presented here show how to create a bean out of concrete class, and then how to inject it into another bean. The fact, that in all cases bean is injected into a field defined as an interface does not matter- all operations are done with beans created out of concrete instances.

I can provide also another catchy example:

```
package creditCards;

interface PaymentCard {
    Boolean isDebitAllowed();
}

   <bean id="card" class="creditCards.PaymentCard">
      <lookup-method name="isDebitAllowed" bean="boolValue"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="boolValue" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <constructor-arg type="boolean" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

As you see here, it is even possible to create a bean out of interface! Still, it is not a interface injection, as IoC contener initializes instanse of this bean by its own. In other words, `card` bean is an initialized object, not an interface, what makes, that the selected answer for this question is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think someone answered your questions [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163175/difference-between-spring-setter-and-interface-injection) 
I also didn't know what Interface injection is until I read this statement from "Pro Spring MVC with web flow book"

"Note that interface-based dependency injection isn’t supported by the Spring Framework. This
means that we need to specify which concrete implementation to inject for a certain interface."

Answer (score 1):

Please  check the below example for iterface injection.

There is a shape interface and 2 concrete classes which imiplements shape namely square and rectangle.

The interface

```
package di.interfaceinjection;
public interface Shape {
    public String shapeName();
    public void displayName();
}
```

2 Implemented classes

```
package di.interfaceinjection;

public class Square implements Shape {

    @Override
    public String shapeName() {
        return "Square";
    }

    @Override
    public void displayName() {
        System.out.println("Square");       
    }

}

package di.interfaceinjection;

public class Rectangle implements Shape{

    @Override
    public String shapeName() {
        return "Rectangle";
    }

    @Override
    public void displayName() {
        System.out.println("Rectangle");        
    }

}
```

Now, we have a class which sets the shape.

```
public class ShapeSetter {

    private Shape shape;

    public Shape getShape() {
        return shape;
    }

    public void setShape(Shape shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
    }

}
```

and finally the configuration

```
<bean id="shape1" class="di.interfaceinjection.ShapeSetter">
    <property name="shape" ref="square"></property>
   </bean>
    <bean id="shape2" class="di.interfaceinjection.ShapeSetter">
    <property name="shape" ref="rectangle"></property>
   </bean>
   <bean id="square" class="di.interfaceinjection.Square"></bean>
   <bean id="rectangle" class="di.interfaceinjection.Rectangle"></bean>
```

Here,

we are injecting different shapes.

```
package di.interfaceinjection;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class InterfaceInjeection {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext appContext  = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("intro.xml");
        ShapeSetter shape = (ShapeSetter)appContext.getBean("shape2");
        shape.getShape().displayName();
    }

}
```