# How to fix 'Coach cannot be resolved to a type' error in Spring

Tags: java, spring, interface, javabeans

I am new to Spring and I have this applicationContext.xml which has the bean, I used ClassPathXmlApplicationContext class to load the bean. and then I also have an Interface called Coach with method getDailyWorkout() and a class called TrackCoach which implements Coach and overrides the method getDailyWorkout(). When I use 
`Coach theCoach = context.getBean("myCoach", Coach.class);`
there is an error

```
    Coach cannot be resolved to a type
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from Coach to Coach
    Coach cannot be resolved to a type
```

I have already tried to edit the bean with different value and also tried reading the documentation, I am pretty sure that I am using the code in the correct way. I have already tried adding a cast to context.getBean() method. I am new to Spring so please help me wit this code.

here is my bean in the file applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="myCoach" class="com.schitiz.springdemo.TrackCoach"></bean>
```

here is my runner class file with main

```
package com.schitiz.springdemo;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class HelloSpringApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Coach theCoach = context.getBean("myCoach", Coach.class);
        System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyWorkout());
            context.close();
    }
}
```

My TrackCoach class is

```
package com.schitiz.springdemo;
public class TrackCoach implements Coach {
    @Override
    public String getDailyWorkout() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Run 5 kms";
    }
}
```

The output must be: Run 5 kms. But it shows error

Comment: I use Eclipse IDE and the spring version is 5.1.9

Comment: try checking below link. Interface injection is explained with example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14684553/6068362

Comment: @Ragas Thank you for the reply but meanwhile I found that I was doing everything right but the Eclipse IDE has some sort of bug. I deleted my Coach interface and recreated it and now it works fine.