# Designing for substitutable dependences in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've been diving into Spring to get back into Java (my professional experience is C#, ASP.NET Core). One item that's somewhat different is Spring's lack of interface-based DI (at least from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248000/spring-interface-injection-example) and more recent Spring documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/dependencies/factory-collaborators.html)). In .NET, for example, I might have a 3-tier application arranged like this:

-API Project
----Controllers\WeatherController.cs
-Core Project
----IWeatherService.cs
-Data Project
----OpenWeatherMapWeatherService.cs

In the DI container configuration, I'd then associate IWeatherService dependencies with OpenWeatherMapWeatherService. If I later want to use the Weather Channel, I could add WeatherChannelWeatherService.cs and update the configuration for IWeatherService to point to WeatherChannelWeatherService.

Is there a common way in Spring to allow dependencies to be substituted in this manner? Or does constructor/setter DI not really provide a mechanism to do this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39857876/6650475) should help.

Comment: Please, tell me where the Spring doc page that you linked says that the injected dependency cannot be an interface.

Comment: Your Spring beans can absolutely be interfaces so not sure the claim Spring has a "lack of interface-based DI"

Comment: @Pino There are three types of dependency injection (https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#FormsOfDependencyInjection), constructor, setter, and interface. When the documentation specifically calls out 2 of those 3, it's a reasonable conclusion, no?

Comment: It could be just a different classification.

Comment: If there's something I'm missing, I guess how does one link an interface injection to its specific dependency?

Comment: `@Configuration public class MyConfiguration { @Bean public MyDaoService myDaoService() { return new MyDaoServiceImpl(); } }`

Comment: Thanks so very much, Zack -- that's exactly what I was hoping to see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Related to 3 tier part of question.
   You are able to implement n-tier(3 or more) architecture by organizing for example each tier in a separate package or for example in a separate source directory.
   You can have one package for the presentation layer and put your controllers in it.
   Another layer for business logic(put all abstraction in this layer) and putting all services in this layer with their implementations.
   Another layer for data access(Data access layer) putting all your entities and repositories in there.
2. Related to substitutable interfaces/components.
   It does not matter where you work but you want to have interfaces and implementations to make it easier to substitute the implementations,
   so in Spring boot you could have a controller(presentation layer) that uses the service interface(service layer) as a type for the service implementation instance
   and pass in it an implementation that is provided(injecting implementation object for example using [@Autowired annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire)), if there is more than one implementation for concrete service you would want to use the
   [@Qualifier annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation)

consider the code provided below

This controller uses the EmployeeService interface as a type for the service implementation object(note that in this example the framework injects the EmployeeService instance automatically without the use of Autowired annotations, this is another method of injecting objects that the platform allows you)

Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeRestController {
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    
    public EmployeeRestController(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> findAll() {
        return employeeService.findAll();
    }
...
}
```

Service Interface:

```
public interface EmployeeService {
    public List<Employee> findAll();
    
    public Employee findById(int theId);
    
...
}
```

Service Implementation:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeServiceImpl(EmployeeDAO employeeDAO) {
        this.employeeDAO = employeeDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Employee> findAll() {
        return employeeDAO.findAll();
    }
    ...
}
```

If you want to have many implementations for EmployeeService check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51766013/spring-boot-autowiring-an-interface-with-multiple-implementations).
It clearly answers to the question of having many implementations of service and injecting desired one in to the desired place using above mentioned @Qualifier annotation

Comment: thanks so much for this incredibly thorough response and references! Spring has a lot of options in terms of how to accomplish something and this really helped clarify everything for me!

Comment: oh, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Interfaces as injection objects in Java Spring. The spring injection will lookup up any implementations for said interface and return an instance.

If you have more than one implementation you will have to give a qualifier annotation to select the implementation you need.